# Pass data to spyOn andReturnValue

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to mock a call to a service which makes a http call.  I'd like to supply fake data in the mock and check against it in my test.

Here is my set up.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MhSearchFormComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.propertyCount = 0;
  spyOn(component._searchService, 'getCount').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

I want to reassign `propertyCount` value in the return of the spy.

Here is my test :

```
  it('should get a count on load', () => {
    expect(component.propertyCount).toBe('1000');
  });
```

I've tried this but it's evidently wrong

`spyOn(component._searchService, 'getCount').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {'Count':1000} });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how your component/service looks like. Please try the below sample. If you face any issue, then please post the component and service template.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MhSearchFormComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.propertyCount = 0;
  // To get injected Service Instance from Component.
  const searchService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SearchService);
  // Observable.of('1000') will ensure the subscribe method and its handling
  // And the subscriber will get '1000' as argument.
  spyOn(searchService, 'getCount').and.returnValue(Observable.of('1000'));

  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should get a count on load', () => {
  expect(component.propertyCount).toBe('1000');
});
```